# RoR DB Design - Do I need to use a :through table?

Tags: ruby, database-design

I'm designing a basic sports application in RoR and I don't know if my database design is correct. For instance, I have:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :home_team
  has_one :away_team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
end
```

However, someone told me the better way to do this is:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams, :through => :game_teams, :limit => 2
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games, :through => :game_teams
end

class Game_Teams < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Is there a reason I would or wouldn't want either design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your first approach will work as it stands. If your `games` table has two fields `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` then your `has_one` associations will have to be something like `has_one :home_team, :class => 'Team'`

Also, `Team has_many :games` will assume that the `game` table has a field `team_id` so you will need to add `:conditions` or maybe `:finder_sql` to get `Team` to look in both `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` to find its games. This illustrates the downside of your first approach, essentially whenever you want to know all the games for a team you have 2 fields to look at.